# Query help; do I need a subquery?

Tags: mysql, drupal-6

(Already posted on drupal.stackexchange.com with no response; since the question is mysql-specific hopefully someone here can help...)

I've inherited this code that runs on our home page. It's used to do a custom display of specific pieces of related info. Here's how things are set up:

We have an article. It has a series of node reference fields that allow us to link related images (actually nodes themselves, which contain a headshot and some text; it's not an actual attached image.) Each of those headshots has a thumbnail created via ImageCache so that we can display a small version in search results and on list-type pages.

We have a new requirement that if the related image node for a specific article has a certain taxonomy term (tid) associated with it, it should display differently than other images.

The existing query (which I did not write) looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.title, nr.teaser, n.nid, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.created), '%M %e, %Y') AS date, f.filepath AS image, cfri.field_related_images_nid as image_id 

FROM node n JOIN node_revisions nr ON n.nid = nr.nid 
LEFT JOIN content_field_related_images cfri ON (n.nid = cfri.nid AND cfri.delta = 0) 
LEFT JOIN content_field_att_file cfaf ON cfri.field_related_images_nid = cfaf.nid 
LEFT JOIN files f ON cfaf.field_att_file_fid = f.fid  
JOIN term_node tn2 ON n.nid = tn2.nid 

WHERE n.status = 1 
AND n.type = 'article'   
AND nr.body LIKE '%kimberly-clark%' 
AND tn2.tid = 143 
ORDER BY n.created DESC LIMIT 3
```

This returns a recordset that looks like this:

```
TITLE         |  TEASER           |  NID |  DATE            |  IMAGE                            | IMAGE_ID
==========================================================================================================
Exec Profile  |  Could you please | 67491 | April 29, 2011  | sites/default/files/kcjones.jpg   | 67572
Unilver Ads   |  Unilever topped  | 67421 | April 20, 2011  | sites/default/files/unilever.jpg  | 66889
```

This is all well and good. But what I need to do is (in the same query, somehow) also return the tid that goes with the image_id from the term_node table. On its own for a single image node that query is simple:

```
SELECT tid FROM term_node WHERE nid = 67572
```

But how do I modify the existing query to bring in the tid based on the image_id found in the main part of the query? I'm guessing I need some kind of subquery, but this is stretching the limits of my sql chops...

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

UPDATE Per request, here are the table structures of all the tables used in the query:

```
-- Table structure for table `content_field_att_file`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `content_field_att_file` (
  `vid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `field_att_file_fid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_att_file_list` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_att_file_data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vid`,`delta`),
  KEY `nid` (`nid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `content_field_related_images`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `content_field_related_images` (
  `vid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `field_related_images_nid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vid`,`delta`),
  KEY `nid` (`nid`),
  KEY `field_related_images_nid` (`field_related_images_nid`),
  KEY `delta` (`delta`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `files`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files` (
  `fid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `filepath` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `filemime` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `filesize` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`fid`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=100810 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `node`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `node` (
  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `language` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `changed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `promote` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `moderate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sticky` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tnid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `translate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`nid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `vid` (`vid`),
  KEY `node_changed` (`changed`),
  KEY `node_created` (`created`),
  KEY `node_moderate` (`moderate`),
  KEY `node_promote_status` (`promote`,`status`),
  KEY `node_status_type` (`status`,`type`,`nid`),
  KEY `node_title_type` (`title`,`type`(4)),
  KEY `node_type` (`type`(4)),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `tnid` (`tnid`),
  KEY `translate` (`translate`),
  KEY `status` (`status`,`type`,`created`),
  KEY `status_2` (`status`,`type`,`created`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=102682 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `node_revisions`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `node_revisions` (
  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `vid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `body` longtext NOT NULL,
  `teaser` longtext NOT NULL,
  `log` longtext NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `format` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`vid`),
  KEY `nid` (`nid`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=102690 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `term_node`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `term_node` (
  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `vid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`tid`,`vid`),
  KEY `vid` (`vid`),
  KEY `nid` (`nid`),
  KEY `tid` (`tid`,`nid`),
  KEY `tid_2` (`tid`,`nid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You're already joining term_node. Why can't you just add tid to the select clause? Or do you mean that you need to look up a different term_node record then the one you're already joining? If so, what are the selection criteria for this record? In your example you just say nid=. Is this the same nid that is already in the select? If not, what is it?

Comment: Because the join on that is returning the tid for n.nid. I need the tid for cfri.field_related_images_nid, which is part of the initial select statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a second join for the `term_node` table and add the column to the select list :

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.title, nr.teaser, n.nid, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.created), '%M %e, %Y') AS date, f.filepath AS image, cfri.field_related_images_nid as image_id, tn_img.tid as image_tid

FROM node n JOIN node_revisions nr ON n.nid = nr.nid 
LEFT JOIN content_field_related_images cfri ON (n.nid = cfri.nid AND cfri.delta = 0) 
LEFT JOIN content_field_att_file cfaf ON cfri.field_related_images_nid = cfaf.nid 
LEFT JOIN files f ON cfaf.field_att_file_fid = f.fid  
JOIN term_node tn2 ON n.nid = tn2.nid
LEFT JOIN term_node tn_img ON cfri.field_related_images_nid = tn_img.nid

WHERE n.status = 1 
AND n.type = 'article'   
AND nr.body LIKE '%kimberly-clark%' 
AND tn2.tid = 143 
ORDER BY n.created DESC LIMIT 3
```

This is the important line : `LEFT JOIN term_node tn_img on  cfri.field_related_images_nid = tn_img.nid`, don't forget to add the column to the select list too !

It is possible that my query is wrong, we don't have much information about the table structure, if it didn't work, post the database schema :)

**updated to reflect discussion in comments**

Comment: I'll try your query first; this is a drupal install so the database is huge. If this doesn't work, I'll try to output the schema for the relevant tables.

Comment: Nope, that returned over 3000 records, when there should only be 3. I'll try to get the table info posted.

Comment: @EmmyS try to substitute the `JOIN` with `INNER JOIN` in the added line.

Comment: Oh, so close... but we need to return node records that don't have a related image (or that have an image but the image doesn't have a tax. term.) The inner join completely eliminated any records that don't have an image.

Comment: @EmmyS use a `LEFT JOIN` then :)

Comment: I tried that too, and it eliminated one of the expected three records. I can't quite figure out why yet; that record has values for both image and image_id (when I run the original query without trying to get tax.terms.) So that record still needs to return, even if there are no tax terms associated with its image.

Answer (score 0):

I am probably missing something, but this should work

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.title, nr.teaser, n.nid, **tn2.tid** DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.created), '%M %e, %Y') AS date, f.filepath AS image, cfri.field_related_images_nid as image_id 

FROM node n JOIN node_revisions nr ON n.nid = nr.nid 
JOIN term_node tn tn2 ON n.nid = tn2.nid
LEFT JOIN content_field_related_images cfri ON (n.nid = cfri.nid AND cfri.delta = 0) 
LEFT JOIN content_field_att_file cfaf ON cfri.field_related_images_nid = cfaf.nid 
LEFT JOIN files f ON cfaf.field_att_file_fid = f.fid  

WHERE n.status = 1 
AND n.type = 'article'   
AND nr.body LIKE '%kimberly-clark%' 
AND tn2.tid = 143 
ORDER BY n.created DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: See comments to initial post; the tn2.tid is included in the where clause to limit the results to n. records that have a tid of 143. I'm looking to include results from cfri, with no limit on the tid, as long as the nid matches the returned cfri.related_images_nid in the recordset.